# Appcenter crashing

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

So, I have been using Elementary OS for a while now without any problems. However, when I logged on today I wanted to download an app from the appcenter, but when I tried to search it's name in the searchbar the appcenter window just closed. Now I can't type more than one character into the searchbar without it crashing and cannot open any of the category tabs. What is going on?

PS: Running it via the terminal gives

```
[INFO 15:40:53.598248] Application.vala:155: App Center version: 0.1.2
[INFO 15:40:53.598292] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.4.0-51-generic
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Seeing a similar issue. Running appcenter from command prompt yields "Client.vala:241: The package id's '' are not valid" and app crashes when trying to search.

Comment: I have the same issue. Maybe they should fix this.

Comment: appcenter[1641]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f85d8e8098c sp 00007ffc5ca2f880 error 4 in libgtk-3.so.0.1800.9[7f85d8cfa000+71a000]